# EF sorting by item property or by child properties depending on situation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am having a sorting issue with Entity Framework 5 code first. I am creating a sort of a forum, and there are two classes in my Model :

- Messages (MessageId, DatePost, Title, Content)
- Comment (CommentId, DatePost, Content, MessageId)

Messages has a navigation collection named Comments, which is well handled by EF Code First and the related configuration.

In the main page of the forum, I'm trying to order the messages by their last comment date, in order to have the last commented messages on top. I wrote this code :

```
_messageRepository
            .GetAll()
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.Comments.Max(c => c.DatePost))
            .ToList();
```

The problem is that when I post a new message, it has no comments, so it goes at the bottom of the page. I would like to combine the last sorting methode with the .OrderByDescending(m => m.Datepost) I had before with doesn't suit my needs anymore...

Any help ? :-)

Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in Linq-to-Objects you would just do:

```
_messageRepository
            .GetAll()
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.Comments.Any() 
                                  ? m.Comments.Max(c => c.DatePost)
                                  : m.Datepost)
            .ToList();
```

However EF may not be able to translate that to SQL.  You could materialize the list first then call `.OrderBy`:

```
_messageRepository
            .GetAll()
            .AsEnumerable()
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.Comments.Any() 
                                  ? m.Comments.Max(c => c.DatePost)
                                  : m.Datepost)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I believe the first query would work in EF without materializing the solution (it did with a similar data set I'm working with at least).

Comment: @Moeri it gets materialized anyway through `ToList()` - it's just doing the sorting on the client rather than in SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much Stanley, that worked! Ocelot was right, no need to materialize the list, and the SQL generated in output is quite sexy. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
_messageRepository
    .GetAll()
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Comments.Max(c => (DateTime?)c.DatePost)
        ?? m.Datepost)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That worked for me thank's!! I finally choosed Stanley's solutions, I prefer without the DateTime? cast